# EF6 (code first) Multiple nav properties on single foreign key property

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

When migrating my data layer from `Telerik` to `EF6` I had POCO *naming issues*. 
The `EF` model is "code first" generated from an existing database. Because i do not want to change the business layer, all migration/configuration needs to be done in the data layer. I also try to keep `EF` code generation from the database unchanged for future maintenance while using partial classes for keeping the legacy code intact.

So `EF` generates poco's with a `FK` reference like this:

```
public partial class MyPoco
{
        public Guid? MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId { get; set; } /* Foreign key database column */

        public virtual MyForeignKeyDatabasePoco { get; set; } /* Navigation property MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId database column */
}
```

This works out of the box since the naming convention is correct (generated)
But now I like to add a navigation property based on the **same database FK** Id (used in the business layer),

```
public partial class MyPoco
{

        [ForeignKey("MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco", "MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId")]  /* <- not possible, no constructor accepts two parms */
        public Guid? MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId { get; set; }   /* Foreign key database column */

        public virtual MyForeignKeyDatabasePoco {get; set; }    /* Navigation property FK MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId database column */

        public virtual MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco {get; set; } /* Navigation property FK MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId database column */
}
```

I tried decorating the Id property with [ForeignKey("MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco")] but then it complains that "MyForeignKeyDatabasePoco" doesn't have a (foreign-)key. I can't set two foreignkey decorators to the id property either.

MyForeignKeyDatabasePoco and MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco are simular, they both exist in the model.

A) Is this possible? 
B) Should I change something in OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) when entity MyPoco is defined (or either or both of the fk poco's)?
C) Should I just get rid of the generated nav property in favor of the legacy business property (not the preferred option btw)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit after bubi commented**

Solved it with inheritance. First the database poco is abstracted and then the application poco inherits from then database poco

```
public abstract partial class MyForeignKeyDatabasePoco 
{
    /* EF generated code */ 
}

public partial class MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco : MyForeignKeyDatabasePoco 
{
    /* additional things todo */ 
}

public partial class MyPoco
{
        public Guid? MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId { get; set; } /* Foreign key database column */

        public virtual MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco { get; set; } /* Navigation property to MyForeignKeyDatabasePocoId database column */
}
```

In the fluent model a DbSet< MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco > is added and in the fluent OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) *modelBuilder.Entity< MyForeignKeyApplicationPoco >();* is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think that it is not possible using attributes if you don't add a property with the foreign key field name. In that case you can use ForeignKey attribute setting the property as the foreign key.

Otherwise you can use fluent configuration (usually I use this way).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
        .HasRequired(t => t.PianoDiRientro)
        .WithMany(t => t.Rates)
        .Map(d => d.MapKey("IdPianoDiRientro"));
```

In this case is one to many relationship (one `PianoDiRientro` many `Rates`) and the foreign key column name is `IdPianoDiRientro`.

Comment: I think you are correct. Not possible with attributes. I've solved it using inheritance. Making the database-poco abstract and the application-poco inheriting the database-poco. Not my ideal solution but it seem to work.